# manage memory allocation exemple project

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, psutil

so i have this script but i dont know how it worsk can someone please explain it to me , all what i know is that we have two types pf used super user and normal user each one got many taskss
that we excecute after extracting from a file.txt
# Permet de mieux gérer le typing (définition des types lors de la signature fonction)
from **future** import annotations

```
# Permet de créer des classes héritant d'énum pour réaliser des énumérations
from enum import Enum

# Gère le multithreading
import threading

# Mise en pause du programme via time.sleep()
import time

# Lecture de la mémoire utilisée
import os, psutil

# Interface graphique
import turtle
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# Shuffle permet de mélanger une liste (utilisé pour la liste des story)
from random import shuffle

__FILENAME__ = "stories.txt"
__KO_SIZE_BYTE__ = 1024

__TIME_TASK_S__ = 5
__NUMBER_BLOCKS_BY_TASK__ = 5

# Booléen permettant de savoir si un super utilisateur a pris la main (mise en pause automatique des utilisateurs normaux)
is_locked_for_super_user = False

### Définition de la classe Block ###
# number_of_block : Nombre de block alloué
# state : status du block (Block.State.FREE ou Block.State.BUSY)
# data : data que le block va stocker (story)
# next_block : reférence du prochaine block
class Block:
  _SIZE_ = 512 * __KO_SIZE_BYTE__

  class State(Enum):
    FREE = 0
    BUSY = 1
  def __init__(self, number_of_blocks : int, state : Block.State, data : str, next_block : Block = None):
    self.number_of_blocks = number_of_blocks
    self.state = state
    self.data = bytearray(data, encoding="utf-8")
    self.data.extend(bytearray(int((Block._SIZE_ * number_of_blocks )- len(data)), ))
    self.next_block = next_block

  def add(self,next_block : Block, index : int = 1) -> int:
    if self.next_block:
      return self.next_block.add(next_block, index + 1)
    else:
      self.next_block = next_block
      return index

### Définition d'une classe MemoryBlock qui représente une liste chainée ###
# block : premier block de la liste chainée
class MemoryBlock:

  def __init__(self, block : Block = None ):
    self.block = block    

  def __getitem__(self, key):
    if key == 0:
      return self.block

    item = self.block.next_block
    for _ in range(1, key):
      item = item.next_block

    return item

  def add(self, block : Block) -> int:
    # manage empty block
    if not self.block:
      self.block = block
      return 0

    return self.block.add(block)

  def remove(self, key):
    if key == 0:
      self.block = self.block.next_block
    else:
      self[key - 1].next_block = self[key].next_block

  def size(self) -> int:
    if not self.block:
      return 0
    size = 1
    current_block = self.block
    while current_block.next_block:
      current_block = current_block.next_block
      size+= 1
    return size      

### Classe Task ###
# lib_task : Libellé de la tache
# time_task : Temps d'éxécution de la tache en seconde
# mem_task : taille allouée à la tache
# level_task : Priorité de la tache (Task.Priority.HIGH ou Task.Priority.LOW)
# state_task : Etat de la tache (Task.State.ACTIVE ou Task.State.SLEEPING)
# treeView : arbre de l'interface graphique qui affiche l'éxécution des taches 
# story : Chaine de caractère à afficher par la tâche en time_task secondes
# block_memory : liste chainée de block
class Task(threading.Thread):
  class Priority(Enum):
    HIGH = 0
    LOW = 1

  class State(Enum):
    ACTIVE = 0
    SLEEPING = 1

  def __init__(self, lib_task : str, time_task : int, mem_task : int, level_task : Priority, state_task : State, treeview : ttk.Treeview, story : str, block_memory : MemoryBlock):
    self.lib_task = lib_task
    self.time_task = time_task 
    self.index_block = block_memory.add(Block(number_of_blocks=int(mem_task / Block._SIZE_), state= Block.State.BUSY, data = story))
    self.story = story
    self.block_memory = block_memory    
    self.level_task = level_task
    self.state_task = state_task
    self.treeview = treeview
    self.block_memory = block_memory
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)

  def run(self):
    self.state_task = Task.State.ACTIVE
    data_to_display = self.block_memory[self.index_block].data.decode()[0:len(self.story)]
    nb_to_display_each_sec = int(len(data_to_display) / self.time_task)
    
    self.treeview.insert("",'end', text=self.lib_task, values = (self.lib_task, ""))

    total_display_chars = nb_to_display_each_sec
    global is_locked_for_super_user
    for i in range(0, self.time_task + 1):      
      while self.level_task == Task.Priority.LOW and is_locked_for_super_user:
        time.sleep(0.5)
      for item in self.treeview.get_children():
          if self.treeview.item(item)["text"] == self.lib_task:
            self.treeview.item(item, values = (self.lib_task, data_to_display[0:total_display_chars]))
            total_display_chars += nb_to_display_each_sec
            break
      time.sleep(1)
    self.treeview.item(item, values = (self.lib_task, data_to_display))
    self.state_task = Task.State.SLEEPING
    self.block_memory[self.index_block].state = Block.State.FREE

### Thread permettant de gérer l'éxécution de toutes les taches ###
# memoryBlock : liste chainée de block 
# stories : liste de chaine de caractères que les taches executerons
# treeView : arbre de l'interface graphique qui affiche l'éxécution des taches 
class TaskManager(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self, memoryBlock: MemoryBlock, stories, priority : Task.Priority, treeView : ttk.Treeview):
    self.memoryBlock = memoryBlock
    self.stories = stories
    self.priority = priority
    self.treeView = treeView
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)

  def run(self):
    global is_locked_for_super_user
    while self.priority == Task.Priority.LOW and is_locked_for_super_user:
        time.sleep(0.5)

    # launch tasks
    shuffle(self.stories)
    tasks = []
    for index, story in enumerate(self.stories):    
      task = Task(lib_task="task " + str(index), time_task=__TIME_TASK_S__, mem_task=Block._SIZE_ * __NUMBER_BLOCKS_BY_TASK__, level_task=self.priority, state_task=Task.State.SLEEPING, treeview=self.treeView, story=story, block_memory=self.memoryBlock)
      task.start()
      tasks.append(task)
      # une tache dormante, une fois arrivé son tour d’exécution, elle donne la main à la suivante.
      while task.state_task == Task.State.SLEEPING:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        
    # Wait until tasks are finished
    for t in tasks:
      t.join()

### Récupère la mémoire utilisée ###
# Retourne la mémoire utilisée en Mo
def get_memory_usage():
  return psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / __KO_SIZE_BYTE__  / 1024 # Mo 


### Lancée par Thread dans le but de superviser le lancement des taches ###
# memoryBlock : liste chainée de block 
# stories : liste de chaine de caractères que les taches executerons
# treeView : arbre de l'interface graphique qui affiche l'éxécution des taches 
def launch_task_manager(memoryBlock : MemoryBlock, stories, priority : Task.Priority, treeView : ttk.Treeview):
  # Clear treeview
  for row in treeView.get_children():
    treeView.delete(row)    

  global is_locked_for_super_user
  if priority == Task.Priority.HIGH:
    is_locked_for_super_user = True

  taskManager = TaskManager(memoryBlock, stories, priority, treeView)
  taskManager.start()
  taskManager.join()

  # garbage collector
  for i in range(memoryBlock.size() -1, -1, -1):
    if memoryBlock[i].state == Block.State.FREE:
      memoryBlock.remove(i)


  if priority == Task.Priority.HIGH:
    is_locked_for_super_user = False

### Extrait toutes les lignes à partir d'un fichier ###
# filename : chemin vers le fichier à lire
# Retourne une liste des lignes lues
def read_stories(filename : str):
  story = open(filename, 'r')
  return [line.rstrip("\n") for line in story.readlines()]

### Supervise la mémoire utilisée et de met à jour l'interface ###
# memory_bar : Jauge de mémoire de l'interface
# memory_desc : Champs label de l'interface descrivant la mémoire utilisé
def monitor_interface(memory_bar : ttk.Progressbar, memory_desc : tk.Text):
  try:
    max_bar = 0
    memory_bar["maximum"] = int(get_memory_usage())
    while True:
      memory_usage = memory_usage = int(get_memory_usage())
      memory_bar["value"] = memory_usage
      if memory_usage >= max_bar:
        max_bar = memory_usage
        memory_bar["maximum"] = max_bar
      
      memory_desc["text"] = str(memory_usage) + ' Mo utilisés / ' + str(max_bar) + ' Mo maximum utilisés'
      time.sleep(1)
  except Exception:
    return

def main():
  # initialize head list empty
  memoryBlock = MemoryBlock()

  # Read story file
  stories = read_stories(__FILENAME__)

  turtle.title("Garbage Collector")  
  turtle.ht()
  window = turtle.getscreen()
  window.setup(800, 600)

  # Create Super user Tasks field
  canvas = window.getcanvas()
  super_tasks_field = ttk.Treeview(canvas.master, columns=["Label", "Execution"], show="headings",  height=20)
  super_tasks_field.heading('Label', text='Label')
  super_tasks_field.column("Label",minwidth=50,width=75) 
  super_tasks_field.heading('Execution', text='Execution')
  super_tasks_field.column("Execution",minwidth=100,width=250) 
  canvas.create_window(-200, 0, window=super_tasks_field)

  # Create super user button
  canvas = window.getcanvas()
  button = tk.Button(canvas.master, text="Super utilisateur", command=lambda: threading.Thread(target=launch_task_manager, args= (memoryBlock, stories, Task.Priority.HIGH, super_tasks_field)).start(), height=2, width=30)
  canvas.create_window(-200, -250, window=button)

  # Create user Tasks field
  canvas = window.getcanvas()
  tasks_field = ttk.Treeview(canvas.master, columns=["Label", "Execution"], show="headings",  height=20)
  tasks_field.heading('Label', text='Label')
  tasks_field.column("Label",minwidth=50,width=75) 
  tasks_field.heading('Execution', text='Execution')
  tasks_field.column("Execution",minwidth=100,width=250)
  canvas.create_window(200, 0, window=tasks_field)

  # Create user button
  canvas = window.getcanvas()
  button = tk.Button(canvas.master, text="Utilisateur ordinaire", command=lambda: threading.Thread(target=launch_task_manager, args= (memoryBlock, stories, Task.Priority.LOW, tasks_field)).start(), height=2, width=30)
  canvas.create_window(200, -250, window=button)

  # Create progress bar for memory usage
  canvas = window.getcanvas()
  memory_usage = ttk.Progressbar(canvas.master, orient='horizontal',mode='determinate', length=750, value=get_memory_usage(), maximum=100)
  canvas.create_window(0,250, window=memory_usage)

  # Create text description for memory usage
  canvas = window.getcanvas()
  memory_usage_description = tk.Label(canvas.master, text="", background="white")
  canvas.create_window(0,275, window=memory_usage_description)

  # Lancement d'un thread permettant de supervisier la mémoire utilisée
  interface_monitoring_th = threading.Thread(target=monitor_interface, args=(memory_usage, memory_usage_description), daemon= False)
  interface_monitoring_th.start()
  window.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':  
    main()
```

Comment: This is an awful lot of code. Is it possible to create a smaller [mcve]?

Comment: the problem iss thats the only example that i found while doing my research ill tranna come up with a more reproducible one once i understand this ine first